# Where to ask questions about car-miniatures

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been browsing all the SE but none of them is about something -car alike besides the mechanic & repair SE.

I have some questions about car-miniatures (the whole car, not model-build packs), where do I ask them?

**My example question**s:

- Build years & rarity of some cars
- Some special types of cars, were they build or not?
- Etc ...

Comment: I couldn't even find anything on Area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/ so ....

Comment: Do you mean miniatures that you build, like models, or just purchase whole like die-cast cars?

Comment: @Catija, the whole build, not model-build packs

Comment: Unfortunately, there can't be an SE for everything... I think you'll be better off somewhere like [this](http://www.modelcarsmag.com/forums/). It's primarily for build kit cars but they do have a forum section for die-cast and resin-cast topics.

Comment: @Catija bummer, thanks anyways! I was hoping for some maybe more-toy ish history section that I couldn't find but to bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As nothing currently seems to exist for this then it's worth proposing a 'Toys and Collectables' idea (or something similar) on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). If there's enough interest, and it fits the format then it could well happen.

To be honest I'm surprised nothing has been suggested before, but potentially that means it has been tried and failed, or just that it's too broad a topic to work (which might be the case - too many 'collectable' genres out there to have one global site for it, but too few specialists to have a bespoke 'Collectable Cars' site).

Either way, if you don't ask you don't get, so put a proposal up there and see what comes of it.